# how to use media query for height in flutter(with const)

Tags: flutter

When working with media query for image height in flutter. (which uses assets.images ) to load image from assets, The media Query is showing this error.

[image]

This is the code which i used

```
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const Image(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *0.2,
              width: 250,
              image: AssetImage('assets/logo/logo.jpg')),
          Text(
            'Login',
            style: GoogleFonts.lato(
              textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, letterSpacing: .5),
            ),


----------


          ),
        ],
      ),

> But it will work if i wrap the image widget with container and specify height for container.
```

Comment: Remove the const keyword added infront of image widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove **const** keyword , Widget is not constant hope it helps you.

refer documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) for **Media Query**

Answer (score 2):

The `height` you passed to `Image` is not a constant because the `context` is not a constant. To fix it, just remove the `const` keyword.